# how can i return file name by using formidable node package?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

hello i am working on mean application.I want the uploaded file name which i encrypted in formidable . How can i send updated file name to other controllers??

```
    app.post('/api/upload', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);
    // var filename = req.body.file;
  // filename=filename.replace(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1),"");
  // uuid = generateUUID();
  // filename = filename+uuid;
    console.log(form);
    console.log(form.parse(req));
    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.name = uuidv4()+'.mp4';
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
      file.name = uuidv4()+'.mp4';
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

i want this api return new file name??

Comment: **i want this api return new file name??** when i  try to run your code i do get the encrypted file name in `console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);`  so you can return that name. what is your trouble here?

Comment: but it didnt return name to my controller.When I try to print file name on console side it print undefined